# How do i toggle off this weird cursor tracer when in texture paint mode? (Blender 2.8 LS)

Tags: texturing, texture-painting, mouse

i got this weird cursor thingy after messing around with my keyboard when blender crashed. This only shows up whenever I left click. [image]

Answer (score 2):

This is the stroke stabilizer, to smooth out strokes.

[image]